# Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL - POWER BI connection failure in a private network

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, powerbi

Connection failure PostgreSQL on Amazon RDS database instance in a private network from PowerBI Desktop & Service.

I have an AWS RDS (PostgreSQL) that is inside a private network - only accessible via a VPN and Bastion Host.

I am able to establish connection from PBI Desktop to "PostgreSQL-RDS Instance." By creating SSH tunnel from my Laptop (localhost) to Bastion Host using ODBC Driver. With this approach all the data is imported onto PBI desktop (import mode).

But our requirement is to establish connection through a direct query to refresh data real time and generate the reports dynamically which I am not able to.

I entered the database credentials into the Power BI desktop tool, and it not working correctly in the Power BI desktop, getting a `TimeOut Error`.

I must use directquery, I can't use import.

Comment: If you have enabled VPC Flow Logs, then you can trace vpc flow logs to check, which aws resource is rejecting the network traffic. For VPC flow logs information please refer [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/vpc-flow-logs-log-and-view-network-traffic-flows/) document from AWS.

Comment: It appears that you have been successful creating a connection via the SSH tunnel. How is your configuration different for the other use-case? Are you still using the SSH tunnel?